# How to set chmod -R 777 . set groups users permission recursively in centos 8

Tags: centos8

I need to set out permission set to chmod -R 777 recursively for every user and group  how would I can able to do it

When applying

```
chmod -R 777 ./
```

I am able to set the permission 777 for all folders and content but not other users are able to change the permission or change the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try the find command

```
$ find path/to/directory/ -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: it works like same as chmod -R 777 ./ no difference in it

Comment: Wait I misread the question. What exactly are you asking? What do you mean by -`but not other users are able to change the permission or change the content.`

Comment: i need to add recursively add permissions to all groups and users

Comment: But 777 does exactly that. All groups and users get full access to it.

Comment: it does not add recursively